# Runge Kutta 2 problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I have the following problem to solve:

[image]

Estimate y(0.1) by rk2 with h=0.1.

Where rk2 it's:

[image]

I replace the second-order ODE by a system of two first-order ODEs:

$
\ \ y_{1}{}'=y_{2}\\
\ \ y_{2}{}'=48.sin(10t)-12.y_{2}-100.y_{1}\\
\ \ y_{1}(0)=0\\
\ \ y_{2}(0)=0
$

Then:

$
\ \ y_{1(n+1)}=y_{1(n)}+\frac{1}{2}.(k_{1}+k_{2})\\
\ \ y_{2(n+1)}=y_{2(n)}+\frac{1}{2}.(q_{1}+q_{2})
$

Where, for n=0:

$
\ \ k_{1}=h.y_{1}{}'(0)=h.y{}'(0)=0\\
$

And now,  here is my question...I am stuck at solving of this constant:

$
\ \ k_{2}=h.y_{1}{}'(0.1)=h.y{}'(0.1)=?\\
$

Where I get the value of $y{}'(0.1)$?.I have the same confusion when calculating the value of $q_{2} (y{}''(0.1)=?)$.Any ideas where it goes wrong?.Thanks for your help, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the computation of $k$ and $q$, lose the derivatives and just use the functions $f$ and $g$ that you found by deriving the first order system, i.e.,

$f(t,y_1,y_2)=y_2$ and  $g(t,y_1,y_2)=48⋅sin(10⋅t)−12⋅y_2−100⋅y_1$.